# intent.resolveActivity returns null on android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT in API 30

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am having problem to pick a pdf file.
Before, the targetSdk is 29 and it's working fine but when I updated it to 30, device with Android 11 and above can't open the file manager to pick the pdf file. Device with version below Android 11 is working fine.
This is the code to create the Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT");
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.OPENABLE");
intent.setType("application/pdf");
```

and this is the code to launch the intent :

```
boolean canBeLaunched = false;
if (intent.resolveActivity(fragment.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
    canBeLaunched = true;
    fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

On debug, intent.resolveActivity returns null on Android 11 and above.

Comment: Dont try to resolve. Just start the intent.

Comment: new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Android 11 were made some changes in package visbility, some info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) and [HERE](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9)

note that [`resolveActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#resolveActivity(android.content.pm.PackageManager)) should return package name of app, which can handle this intent. Thats against freshly introduced rules and new policy as above

instead try to run `startActivityForResult` strictly without your `if` and wrap it in `try { ... } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){}`

```
boolean canBeLaunched;
try {
    fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    canBeLaunched = true
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
    canBeLaunched = false
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for writing the solution. I just applied it and it's working well.
Should I make a validation to only call this code on Android 11 and above? Or is it okay to use this code for all Android version?

Comment: if you don't need app/package name at all and you are checking only `!= null` then you can stay with new way on all Android versions